# Access Django M2M values in queryset without looping

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I receive some data through Ajax that allows me to do some filtering on a model that has some m2m relations (say Model). I get a queryset, say "content" that I then need to send back using json. Here are simplified lines of code:

```
content =  Models.objects.all()
content = content.values
return JsonResponse({"data":list(content)})
```

It was working fine but the project changed and I now need to include the values of some of the m2m related models attached to Model to each queryset result instances, problem is that content=Model.objects.all() will of course not give me these values without some looping so I am stuck. I remember using a depth option in DRF that would have done the job here but unfortunately I cannot do this now as the project is too advanced and live. Any way to add directly in the queryset the results of the m2m related values ?
Many many thanks

Adding simplified models here :

```
class Content(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    pathology = models.ManyToManyField(Pathology, null=True, blank=True)
    organs = models.ManyToManyField(Organ, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Titre",
                              max_length=255, null=True, blank=False)
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtaildocs.Document',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    description = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)

class Pathology(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Organ(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Please share the relevant models, don't use `.values()`: use a serializer...

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: in dev sqlite and pgsql in production

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't* use [**`.values(…)`** <sup>[Django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html), these erode the logic in the model layer. Furthere you can not use `.values(…)` *bidirectionally*: you can only convert records into dictionaries, not deserialize dictionaries into model objects.

In *PostgreSQL* you can make use of [**`ArrayAgg`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg), this is an aggregate that *only* works for PostgreSQL, and furthermore it is probably not ideal either, since again it makes adapting the serialization process cumbersome. You can use this as:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg

content = Models.objects.values().annotate(
    organs=ArrayAgg('organs__pk')
)
return JsonResponse({"data":list(content)})
```

Using The [*Django REST framework*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is however still possible with the current view. You can install this framework and define a serializer with:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organs = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then in the view you can work with:

```
contents = Models.objects.prefetch_related('organs')
serializer = ContentSerializer(contents, many=True)
return JsonResponse({'data': serializer.data})
```

Answer (score 1):

Willem's solution using DRF is correct yet returns only the ID of the related fields. I suppose there is a way to change this and get another field yet instead I found another way with no override needed:

```
class OrganSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organ
        fields = (('title'),)

class PathologySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pathology
        fields = (('title'),)

class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organs = OrganSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    pathology = PathologySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = '__all__'
```

Rest of the solution was spot on.
Didn't try the prod PGSQL yet